# Hermitian metric on conic Kaehler-Einstein setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds

I have a technical question :

Consider the triple $(M,D,\omega)$ where $M$ is a Fano manifold, $D$ is a smooth divisor whose Poincare dual is $\lambda c_1(M)$ and $\omega$ is a conic Kaehler -Einstein metric on $M$ with cone angle $2\pi\beta$ along $D$. Let $S$ is a difining section of $D$ . In local holomorphic coordinates $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ , write $S=f\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_1}\wedge...\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial z_n}\big)$ and $H(.,.)$ be a Hermitian metric on $K_M^{-1}$  and $\omega=i\sum g_{\alpha\bar\beta}dz_\alpha\wedge d\bar z_\beta$

> then $H$ can be represented by
>
> $$\text{det}(g_{\alpha\bar\beta})^{\frac{1}{\mu}}\mid f
>  \mid^{\frac{2(1-\beta)}{\mu}}$$
>
> for some $\mu$

This fact has been appeared in most of the papers about Kahler-Einstein metrics. But I am looking for a reason!

See this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4669.pdf) for details

Comment: What is the relation between $H$, $\omega$ and $S$?

Comment: This is certainly false if you don't impose any relation among $H$, $\omega$ and $S$, since as you wrote it now $H$ is an arbitrary Hermitian metric on $K_M^{-1}$.

Comment: You just took your notations from page 16 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4669.pdf. I believe everything is explained there.

Comment: In fact for defining section $S$ of divisor $D$ there exists unique $H$ which satisfies $\int_MH(S,S)\omega^n=1$. Tian left this part without any detatil. So my question make sense